# Basic Python: Function giving me a global name error

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that will determine if a given number if "ugly".  It's ugly if the only prime factors it has are 2, 3, and 5 (it can have less than all 3 but no others).

I get an error, saying: "Line 22: NameError: global name 'getPrimeFactors' is not defined".

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
import math

class Solution(object):
    def isPrime(self, num):
        for i in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(num))):
            if num % i == 0:
                return false
        return true

    def getPrimeFactors(self, num):
        primeFactors = []
        for i in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(num))):
            if isPrime(i) and num % i == 0:
                primeFactors.append(i)
        return primeFactors

    def isUgly(self, num):
        """
        :type num: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        primeFactors = getPrimeFactors(num)
        for factor in primeFactors:
            if factor != 2 and factor != 3 and factor != 5:
                return false
        return true
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you coming from c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getPrimeFactors` as `self.getPrimeFactors(num)` because it's defined as a method inside the class `Solution`:

```
primeFactors = self.getPrimeFactors(num)
```

The same for `isPrime`:

```
if self.isPrime(i) and num % i == 0:
```

Other issues:

- `range` arguments should be `int` not `float`, so use `int` instead of `math.floor`:

  ```
  range(2, int(math.sqrt(num)))
  ```
- Use `True` not `true` in python

  ```
  return True
  ```